VS Code Dev Container - very slow start
I'm using VS Code with docker and Dev Container extension.
It is working fine but every time I start it I see (among other log lines)
[1597 ms] Start: Run: docker -v
[1645 ms] Start: Resolving Remote
[136401 ms] Failed to fetch control manifest: 
[136404 ms] Start: Run: docker compose version --short

I have the following config for docker proxy
$ cat ~/.docker/config.json
{
 "proxies": {
   "default": {
     "httpProxy": "http://proxy.org.com:81",
     "httpsProxy": "http://proxy.org.com:81",
     "noProxy": ".org.com"
   }
 }
}

How can I fix this so it will be able to fetch whatever it needs and start faster?
I don't see the same thing when running the same docker container from bash in WSL.

Found the answer: Add 127.0.0.1 containers.dev to /etc/hosts
Thank to
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8808

My problem was similar to yours, but perhaps slightly different, with a really long wait on "Start: Resolving Remote"...
Updating my "Dev Containers" and "Remote Development" extensions fixed the slowness issue for me on Oct 30, 2024 ✅
